# The condition for the existence of a symmetric form for the reflection formula $f(1-x)= \chi (x) f(x)$

Tags: functional-equations, symmetry, reflection

Suppose we have a functional equation in the form
$$f(1-x)=\chi (x)  f(x)$$
with given function $\chi (x)$. What is the condition on the function $\chi (x)$ so that we can write this reflection relation  in a symmetric form $$\xi(1-x)=\xi(x) ?$$
I have the only simple answer: the $\chi (x)$ function should be of the type:$$\chi (x)= \phi(1-x)/\phi(x)$$ then $\xi(x)=f(x)/\phi(x)$.  *Is it correct?*

**Edit**
I want to illustrate my question with an example.

Let first $\chi (x)$ be  $$  \chi (x)= \frac {\pi}{\sin\pi x  (\Gamma (x))^2} $$ 
And we have functional equation $\Gamma (x) \Gamma (1-x)=\frac {\pi}{\sin\pi x}$ without symmetric form.

Let then $\chi (x)$ be  $$  \chi (x)= \frac { \pi^{-\frac {x}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{x}{2})} { \pi^{-\frac {1-x}{2}} \Gamma(\frac{1-x}{2})} $$
Here $\phi(x)=  ({ \pi^{-\frac {x}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{x}{2})})^{-1} $ and we have symmetric form with $\xi(x)=\zeta(x)/\phi(x)$

Comment: I have the feeling that you can always write $f(1-x)=\chi (x)  f(x)$ for an appropriate $\chi$ and set $\xi(x) = f(x)f(1-x)$ or some other symmetric form. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @G.Carugno, I mean the case when we *don't know the expliсit expression* for $f$ and do have  an explicit expression for $ \chi$ and if it is  in the form $\chi (x)= \phi(1-x)/\phi(x)$ we can get symmetrical (but also unknown) function $ \xi (x) = f(x)/ \phi(x)$

Comment: Taking the log derivative we have $F(x)-F(-x) = G(x)$ where $F(x) = f'/f(1/2+x), G(x) = \chi'/\chi(1/2+x)$ so $G$ is odd so $G(x) = H(x)-H(-x)$ and $F(x)+H(x)$ is odd ie. $f(1/2+x) h(1/2+x)$ is even where $h(x) = \exp(\int H(1/2- x)$. With $f(x) = \zeta(x)$ then $h(x) = \pi^{-x/2} \Gamma(x/2)$

Comment: I still want to understand the answer to my question As far as I can see the function $\chi$ must be the kind of $ \chi (x)= \phi(1-x)/\phi(x) $ to satisfy the original functional equation   $f(1-x)=\chi (x)  f(x)$ hence the additional condition for the existence of a symmetric form is not required

Answer (score 2):

There is not much going on here. Just to make that clear, without loss of essential generality, suppose that we have any function $\ f(x)\ $ and define
$\ g(x) := f(x) - f(-x).\ $ Now we have
 $\ g(-x) = f(-x) - f(-(-x)) = f(-x) - f(x) = -g(x).\ $ Thus, $\ g(x)\ $ is an 
odd function as in [**Even and odd functions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions). In fact, it is twice the **odd part** of $\ f(x).\ $ Further, it follows that by adding **any** even function to $\ f(x)\ $ we can recover the same odd function $\ g(x).\ $

In your case, addition and subtraction is replaced by multiplication and division, and also the involution $\ x \to -x\ $ is replaced by $\ x \to 1-x.$